# What is the shortcut for multiplying two numbers together?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to multiply $75$ and $25$ in my head.

I thought I could do $70 \times 20$ and then add that to $5 \times 5$.

That gets me $1,400 + 25 = 1,425,$ but $75 \times 25 = 1,875.$ Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$75 \times 25 = (70+5)\cdot(20+5) = 70\cdot20 + \color{red}{5\cdot20 + 70\cdot5} + 5\cdot5.$$

You forget to add $$\color{red}{5\cdot20 + 70\cdot5},$$

i. e. $\color{red}{450}$, to your sum.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the distributive property: $$(70 + 5) \times (20+5) = 70 \times 20 + 70 \times 5 + 20 \times 5 + 5 \times 5$$

The best shortcut for this in my opinion is the following arithmetic trick:

$$(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$$

The key is now realizing that if you take $a$ to be the average of the numbers, and $b$ to be the distance to the average, you get something nice. Since both numbers end in $5$, the average is a number that ends in $0$. In this case, it's $50$. The distance to the average is $25$. Unfortuantely, this method requires you to know the square of a number ending in $5$, but more on that in a sec.

Assuming for the moment you know your square tables perfectly, this lets you compute products where the distance is an integer rapidly. You know it's just $50^2 - 25^2 = 2500 - 625 = 1875$. If you do the usual multiplication algorithm in your head, the expansion above shows you there are $4$ terms, and you have to add them. So it takes 7 steps to do multiplication this way. If you have your squares memorized, this process works in 3 steps. You can learn to do this very fast if you practice!

Now, for the secondary trick of knowing squares that end in $5$. The key here is again an algebraic gimmick:

$$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$$

This is a very important formula. The key here is that if we're in the special form of $(a\cdot10 + b)^2$ we get $100a^2+20ab + b^2$. Now $0 \leq a \leq 9$ by assumption our number is of the above form, and $b = 5$, so this simplifies further $100a^2 + 100a + 25= 100(a^2 + a)+25$ This is super simple and you can figure it out immediately.

So for $25$ we have $ a= 2$ and the square is $100(2^2 + 2) + 25 = 625$

Answer (score 1):

The area of the *whole* rectangle, consisting of four smaller rectangles, is $75\times25$.

The *red rectangles* are those ones which areas you *omitted* in your calculation $$(70\times20)+(5\times5).$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$75\times25=(70+5)\times(20+5)\ .$$
If you multiply out the right hand side you get $70\times20$ and $5\times5$, but you get other terms as well.

See if you can supply the details and finish the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align}75 \cdot 25 & = (70 + 5)(20 +5) \\
& = (70\cdot 20) + \mathbf{(70 \cdot 5) + (5 \cdot 20)} + (5\cdot 5) \\& \neq (70 \cdot 20) + (5\cdot 5) 
\end{align}

Perhaps your were attempting the following
\begin{align}
75 \cdot 25 & = (75)(20 +5) = 75 \cdot20 + 75 \cdot 5?
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let me be very clear: (a+b)(c+d) *does not equal* ac+bd. However, there is a way to separate out the problem. We can change $75*25$ into $(70+5)*(25)$, or $70*25+5*25$, which is a lot easier of a problem. The general case is that we can separately multiply each place value, and add all of the products. **Only separate out one side**. If you do both sides, the math quickly becomes very complicated, as you then have to multiply everything by everything else. This is a nice general method to multiply two digit numbers.

Other method:

Notice that $25*4=100$. Notice that $75*25=(4*18+3)*25=4*25*18+3*25=1800+3*25=1875.$

Answer (score 0):

Lets take your example of $75\times25$. Doing this in your head it is always easiest to multiple a number by something like $10$ or $2$ (neither applicable here) so look for these first. If this fails splitting one of the numbers up into each approprite magnitude is the next easiest method:
$$75\times25=75\times(10\times2)+75\times5$$
and this could be repeated again to give:
$$75\times5=(70\times5)+(5\times5)$$
This requires remembering no formulas, just splitting the numbers up and remembering to multiply by $10$ the correct number of times. However, if you want a formula for this then recall:
$$(a+b)(c+d)=ab+ad+bc+bd$$
and so:
$$(70+5)\times(20+5)=(70\times20)+(70\times5)+(5\times20)+(5\times5)$$
and these are all easy times tables that a lot of people remember anyway.